# Do I need to active .NET Core MVC Model Validation or is it activated by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Testing my web API (nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCoreAll 2.0.5) I run into strange issues with the model validation using annotations.

I have (for example) this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] RequestModel request) 
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
  {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  // create
  request.Name.DoSomething();      


  return Created(...);

}
```

I defined my RequestModel as follows:

```
public class RequestModel
{
  [Required]
  public string Name {get; set};

}
```

My problem although I defined RequestModel.Name as [Required] it is null (if Name is not present in the json from the body. Which I thought should not happen since it is marked as [Required] and be automatically appear as ModelState error.

Given [this link to the specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation) they use Bind(....).

So my question?
Do I have to enable it everytime or should it work out of the box or how is it intended to be used?

If I annotate it with [Required] I would assume that at least ModelState.IsValid returns false if it is not present.

Using Bind in the link seems a bit complicated for me in cases where I have multiple objects nested into each other.

---

**Edit 1: created a MVC data validation test bed**
To better visualize what I mean and so everyone can easily experiment on their own I created the small demo [.NET Core MVC data validation test bed](https://github.com/MontyGvMC/.NET-Core-MVC-data-validation-test-bed) on GitHub.

You can download the code, start it with VS 2017 and try it out your own using the swagger ui.

Having this model:

```
public class StringTestModel2
{
    [Required]
    public string RequiredStringValue { get; set; }
}
```

And testing it with that controller:

```
  [HttpPost("stringValidationTest2")]
  [SwaggerOperation("StringValidationTest2")]
  public IActionResult StringValidationTest2([FromBody] StringTestModel2 request)
  {
    LogRequestModel("StringValidationTest2", request);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      LogBadRequest(ModelState);
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    LogPassedModelValidation("StringValidationTest2");

    return Ok(request);
  }
```

The results are far way from expected:

1. Giving a null (not the string "null") is allowed and return 200 OK
2. Giving an int is allowed an returns 200 OK (it gets converted to a string)
3. Giving a double is allowed and returns 200 OK (if possible it gets converted to string, if not convertible (mixing points and semicolons return 400 Bad Request)
4. if you just send empty curly brackets and leave RequiredStringValue undefined it passes and returns 200 OK (with the string as null).

Leaving me (for now) with one of the follwoing conclusions:

1. either MVC data validation does not work out of the box
2. either does not work as expected (if one marks a property as required it should be made sure it is there)
3. either MVC data validation is broken
4. either MVC data validation is completly useless
5. we are missing some important point (like the Bind[])

Comment: It should work out of the box. You do not need to activate anything. If you not want to check the model state in every controler action you could use an action filter.

Comment: If it should work out of the box how can it be that the required Name is null and validation does not throw an error automatically?

Comment: Are you sure that the string doesn't contain a space or that anything simluar could have happened.

Comment: Yes I am sure. My real world model contained multiple strings and in swagger I missed to add one to the json. The error occured when I tried to update the database (in the db it is nut nullable) with the null value. Debugging it showed the missing but required value was just null.

Comment: Actually it should even work if it contained only whitespaces. Can you reproduce this problem with the model you added above? Or does it only happen for models with nested  objects?

Comment: Well, the null value was not in any nested class but in the 'root'. I am currently building a dedicated test application. Hope to be finished tommorow.

Comment: `[Bind]` is not necessary (all properties are bound by default), and in any case, you are editing data so you should always be using a view model which makes `[Bind]` redundant. `ModelState` will be invalid in the code you have shown unless you have not sent any name/value pairs relating to `RequestModel` in which case `request` would be `null` and therefore there is no validation to be performed

Comment: @NtFreX I reproduced my problem in the public github repo linked in edit one

Comment: @StephenMuecke validation with Required seems not to work at all as shown in my Edit 1 above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what your getting at. Validation works perfectly out of the box. Don't have time to look at your test project now, but will have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get ModelValidation automatically as part of using/deriving from controller (I believe it is in the MVC middleware) but, unfortunately, this does not include null checks. So you need to explicitly check the parameter is NULL as well as the ModelState check.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] RequestModel request) 
{
     if (request == null || !ModelState.IsValid) 
     {
         return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }

     ...
```

Comment: In edit 1 I proved it does not work out of the box (at least not as expected)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use

```
services.AddMvc();
```

so it should work by default.

But it doesn't work just as you expect: instead of returning 400 status code it invalidates model state and lets you manage action result.
You can create an attribute class to automatically return "Bad request"

```
internal class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(
                new ApiError(
                    string.Join(" ",
                        context.ModelState.Values
                            .SelectMany(e => e.Errors)
                            .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage))));
        }
    }
}
```

where `ApiError` is a custom ViewModel for error results.

Now you can mark controllers or actions with this attribute to achieve a behavior you expect to have by default.

If you want this behavior for all methods just change your `AddMvc` line to something like this:

```
services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute()));
```

Answer (score 0):

After further experimenting around I found the answer.

> Does the data validation need to be activated?

Answer: it depends on your configure services method:

No, it does not need to be activated if you use

```
services.AddMvc();
```

Yes, it needs to be activated if you use

```
services.AddMvcCore()
  .AddDataAnnotations(); //this line activates it
```

This [article](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/07/difference-between-addmvc-addmvcore/) brought me to the answer.